# implemented CameraX but can’t enable front flash when taking a selfie, Solution?

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

I implemented CameraX but can’t enable front flash when taking a selfie. However my stock camera app is working well but CameraX is not. Did anybody face a similar issue before?

I implemented CameraX but can’t enable front flash when taking a selfie.

Answer (score 0):

Use below:

```
String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[1];
cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
```

You have to give 1 in your getCameraIdList. As getCameraIdList() accepts 2 values, 0 for back camera and 1 for front camera.

It worked for me.